# Eliminar un dato de un registro en sql

Tags: sql

Como puedo eliminar un dato de un registro en sql,

Ejemplo:

```
nombre apellido edad
miguel   lopez   29
juan     perez   27
```

Si solo quiero eliminar el nombre de miguel, pero no su apellido ni su edad????
Podrian ayudarme???

Comment: Hola y bienvenida a Stack Overflow. Si alguna de las respuestas soluciona tu inquietud, te sugiero a aceptarla con el check que aparece bajo los votos, con eso ganan reputación tu y el autor de la respuesta que aceptes. También te invito a hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas el funcionamiento de la comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

Primero de todo, no acabo de entender tu pregunta, probablemente porqué no estás familiarizado con el manejo de bases de datos SQL.

El concepto de eliminar (`delete`) es el de eliminar filas. Para eliminar una fila debemos hacer referencia a una clave única (campo/s que identifica inequívocamente cada una de las filas.).

Entiendo que lo que buscas es "borrar" los campos "nombre" donde este sea "miguel". Ese concepto de eliminar no existe, pero si que puedes sobre escribir dejándolo en blanco (cadena vacía) o bien sustituyéndolo por otro nombre.

En ese caso debes hacer

```
UPDATE tabla SET nombre = '' where nombre = 'miguel'
```

Esto dejará en blanco **todos** los nombre 'miguel' de la tabla. Si tienes una clave primaria y solo deseas eliminar uno de ellos, sería (suponiendo que idTabla = 10)

```
UPDATE tabla SET nombre = '' where idTabla = 10
```

Por supuesto, el resto de campos quedarían inalterados.

Comment: gracias n.n....

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que ejecutar una sentencia UPDATE (actualización):

```
UPDATE TablaPersonas SET NOMBRE="" WHERE apellido = "lopez" AND EDAD = 29
```

Ten en cuenta que con esto *'eliminarás'* (es más correcto decir que dejarás en blanco) todos los registros que tengan lopez de apellido y la edad 29... para evitar esto se suele identificar cada registro con un id o identificador único. En el caso en que tu tabla lo tuviese, en la clausula WHERE es lo que tendría que utilizar, en lugar del apellido y la edad, por ejemplo:

```
UPDATE TablaPersonas SET NOMBRE="" WHERE idPersona = 223476234
```

Comment: ok, gracias n.n